# Yet another "multiple target patterns" makefile error

Tags: java, makefile

I tried looking around, but all of the questions I saw here were too high-level for me to understand.

Here's my makefile:

```
compile: bin src cmp
bin: mkdir bin
src: find src -name "*.java" > sources.txt
cmp: javac -cp biuoop-1.4.jar -d bin @sources.txt
run: java -cp biuoop-1.4.jar:bin:src/resources Ass6Game
jar: jar -cmf Ass6Game.jar Manifest.txt -C bin . -C src resources
```

When I try to run `make compile`, I get the "multiple target patterns" error. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile syntax is incorrect.

The [syntax of a make rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax) is

> In general, a rule looks like this:
>
> ```
> targets : prerequisites
>    recipe
>    …
> ```
>
> or like this:
>
> ```
> targets : prerequisites ; recipe
>    recipe
> ```

Whereas you have your recipe lines in the prerequisite location and so the `:` in the java command is confusing make.

Your makefile should look like this

```
compile: bin src cmp
bin: ; mkdir bin
src: ; find src -name "*.java" > sources.txt
cmp: ; javac -cp biuoop-1.4.jar -d bin @sources.txt
run: ; java -cp biuoop-1.4.jar:bin:src/resources Ass6Game
jar: ; jar -cmf Ass6Game.jar Manifest.txt -C bin . -C src resources
```

or like this

```
compile: bin src cmp
bin:
        mkdir bin
src:
        find src -name "*.java" > sources.txt
cmp: 
        javac -cp biuoop-1.4.jar -d bin @sources.txt
run:
        java -cp biuoop-1.4.jar:bin:src/resources Ass6Game
jar:
        jar -cmf Ass6Game.jar Manifest.txt -C bin . -C src resources
```

or to actually use what make provides for you a bit more something more like this

```makefile
JAR := biuoop-1.4.jar
SOURCES := $(shell find src -name '*.java')
# Or if src is a single directory without sub-directories
#SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.java)

GAMEJAR := Ass6Game.jar

.PHONY: all
all: $(JAR)

bin:
        mkdir bin

$(JAR): $(SOURCES) | bin
        javac -cp $@ -d bin $^

# See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets for what `FORCE` is doing here.
$(GAMEJAR): FORCE
        jar -cmf $@ Manifest.txt -C bin . -C src resources

FORCE: ;

.PHONY: run
run: $(GAMEJAR)
        java -cp $(JAR):bin:src/resources $(GAMEJAR)
```

which follows the [Rules of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/) a bit better and actually lets make intelligently rebuild your files as necessary.